Sample complexity of covariance matrix estimation of a Gaussian random variable (with explicit constants)
I'm seeking an explicit bound for the number of samples required to estimate the covariance matrix of a Gaussian distribution. In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027v7 (end of page 31), the following result is stated:
"Consider an arbitrary centered Gaussian distribution in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ . For every $ \varepsilon \in (0,1) $ and $ t \geq 1 $, the following holds with probability at least $ 1 - 2\exp(-t^2 n) $:
If $ N \geq C(t / \varepsilon)^2 n $, then $ \|\Sigma_N - \Sigma\| \leq \varepsilon \|\Sigma\| $, where $ \Sigma $ is the true covariance matrix, and $ \Sigma_N $ is the empirical covariance matrix computed from $ N $ samples. The matrix norm considered is the operator norm (largest singular value)."
Could you please point me to a reference where this statement is proven with explicit constants $C$, or provide the value of $ C $?

Have you gone to the proof you link? Using the right corollary (for gaussian, not subgaussian), etc., you should be able to track down explicit constants.
